# Automated header change using fancyhdr environment

Tags: fancyhdr

I would like to change the fontsize in the right header while employing the `\pagestyle{fancy}` layout using the automated section title change provided by fancyhdr package.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,danish,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
\lipsum
\section{Example}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Immediately after you specify the pagestyle, use the `\fancyhead` macro to redefine what should be in the header.  Here's an example where I make the section name the size of a footnote.

The [`fancyhdr` documenation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) contains more details.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize\textsl{\leftmark}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
\lipsum
\section{Example}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```